# How can I go through different levels in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've been reading a lot of documentation on how to iterate a Dictionary with a foreach, but I don't quite understand how I can go through the levels it has. For example:

I have "params" Dictionary, I add string and object values ​​to it, with `.Add()`, and to one of them I add a level called "item".

From what I understand, with the Foreach(KeyValueaPair<>) it is to iterate through the Dictionary. Do I need to use another foreach(KeyValuePair<>) to be able to loop through the second level?

For example, I want "param" to get the value of the element that Posnr brings

```
 IDictionary<string, object> params = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            params.Add("Customerid", zwCustomer.Customerid);
            params.Add("PedidoCli", zwCustomer.PedidoCli);
            params.Add("PedidoSap", zwCustomer.PedidoSap);

            params.Add("TFacturaMat", new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {
                    "item", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        {"Vbeln", zfacturaMats.Vbeln},
                        {"Posnr", zfacturaMats.Posnr},
                        {"Matnr", zfacturaMats.Matnr},
                    }
                },
            });

           foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in parametros)
           {
                param = $"{item.Key} : {item.Value}";
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do that directly. The `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class of the .NET library already does all that magic for you.

With the foreach loop

```
           foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in params)
           {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} : {item.Value}");
           }
```

you already iterate trough all the elements of your dictionary. From an usage point of view this works exactly the same as if params was a List (except that there's no guaranteed order).

If you want a particular element, you have multiple possibilities, but in the easiest case you can just get an element by `var myValue = params["PosNr"]`. Alternatively you can use the `TryGetValue()` method to test whether a certain key is present.

So bottom line: It's interesting to know how a dictionary works internally, but when you use the .NET libraries, you don't have to care about that. Iterating and accessing works just out of the box.

Comment: And if I want a particular TValue from an element how can i get it?

Comment: You mean a key from a value? In that case, you need to iterate (use a foreach loop) and compare the values manually. A dictionary is optimized for fast lookups on the key, but lookups on the value are slow.

Comment: I´m usinga foreach loop, but only need the value

Comment: foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in params)
           {    
                var cuit1 = params["Kunnr"];}

Comment: No, that is pointless. If you only need the value you don't need a foreach loop. Just use `var myValue = params["PosNr"]` (without loop). The dictionary does all the magic for you.